# Pass default AjaxOption on every Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to pass a default AjaxOption value on every single Ajax.BeginForm. So I don't have to pass AjaxOption value everytime I call Ajax.BeginForm. Is this possible in ASP MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create your own extension method?

```
public static class MyAjaxHelper
{
    public static MvcForm BeginFormCustom(this AjaxHelper ajax, string action, string controller)
    {
        var myOptions = new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST"
        }
        return ajax.BeginForm(action, controller, myOptions);
    }
}
```

Then use like:

```
@using MyAjaxHelper    

@using (Ajax.BeginFormCustom("Action", "Controller")) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm fairly new in MVC. This may seem to be a very idiotic question to ask but, where do I place this method? Do I have to change that in System.Web.MVC.ajax or something like that?

Comment: Answer edited.  You will need to make a new static class (this is just how C# extension methods work, not MVC specific).  Your view may or may not the `@using MyAjaxHelper` at the top, depending on if it's in another namespace or not.